# Show to_csv data in separate tabs with sep ='\t' does not work

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Guys i got a problem with python, when want to save data to csv and see a proper excel file, each data in separate tab, but now i get all data in one tab. What should i use in sep to see all data columns in separate tabs? (when i print result in python, i see proper all data in  columns not in one line)

```
output_bh.to_csv(path,  na_rep = 'empty', header = 1, index = False, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Isn't this a problem with excel loading it seeing as tab delimited is a supported format for a csv?, you could remove the `sep` arg which will default to comma separated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to save as an Excel file with multiple *worksheets*.

Let's say you have two DataFrames:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Y': [2,3,4,5,6]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,4,3,2,1], 'B': [6,5,4,3,2]})
```

You can save these into an Excel file using [to_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

```
>>> writer = ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
>>> df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
>>> df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
>>> writer.save()
```

This creates two worksheets, each with the contents of `df1` and `df2` respectively.

[image: Excel screenshot]